# Pandas - Exibição após groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Como faço para que a coluna Escritórios não fique em branco, repetindo assim o nome do escritório?

```py
mun_df = planta_df[['Empresas', 'Escritórios', 'Municípios', 'Estados']]
mun_df = mun_df.groupby(['Empresas', 'Escritórios', 'Municípios']).count()
mun_df = mun_df.rename(columns={'Estados': 'Acessos'})

mun_df.to_excel('Disponibilidade.xlsx', sheet_name='Municípios')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia compartilhar um pouco mais do código por gentileza? Como a `planta_df` está estruturada, que dados há nela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `reset_index()` é o seu amigo neste caso. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Escritorios": ["A", "A","A","A","A"], "Municipios": ["Aruja", "Poa", "Poa", "Aruja", "Poa"], "Acessos": [1, 2, 2, 1, 2]})

>>> df
  Escritorios Municipios  Acessos
0           A      Aruja        1
1           A        Poa        2
2           A        Poa        2
3           A      Aruja        1
4           A        Poa        2
```

### Agrupando dados

```
>>> df.groupby(["Escritorios", "Municipios"])["Acessos"].sum()

Escritorios  Municipios
A            Aruja         2
             Poa           6
Name: Acessos, dtype: int64
```

### Agrupando dados e usando o reset_index()

```
>>> df.groupby(["Escritorios", "Municipios"])["Acessos"].sum().reset_index()

  Escritorios Municipios  Acessos
0           A      Aruja        2
1           A        Poa        6
```

Ou seja, basta atribuir a um novo dataframe e salvar para Excel